# How to download image from URL and store in path then set image in imageview from path

Tags: java, android

I am new for android. In my app, I have a listview  with image. I want to download image from url and store in path(if image not exists in path). Then set image in imageView from path. I did but some issues is there.

My issues:

1. First time download, it shows all image one by one in each item in ListView. Finally, set it set perfect image.
2. Set image from path means, It took much time to set image.

Please anyone fix my issues.

Here my code:

My adapter code:

```
 if (ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl))) {

        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl));
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Picasso.with(context)
               .load(new File(path))
               .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
               .error(R.drawable.error)
               .into(holder.menuImage);

    } else {
        new ImageDownloaderTask(list.get(position).imageUrl, holder.menuImage, ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl)).execute();
    }
```

ImageDownloaderTask.java:

```
public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> {
    private String requestUrl, imagename_;
    private ImageView view;
    private Bitmap bitmap ;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    public ImageDownloaderTask(String requestUrl, ImageView view, String _imagename_) {
        this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        this.view = view;
        this.imagename_ = _imagename_ ;
    }
    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestUrl);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = new URL( requestUrl ).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        if(!ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(imagename_))
        {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
        }
    }
}
```

ImageStorage.java:

```
public class ImageStorage {
    public static String saveToSdCard(Bitmap bitmap, String filename) {

        String stored = null;

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        File folder = new File(sdcard.getAbsoluteFile(), "tam");//the dot makes this directory hidden to the user
        folder.mkdir();
        File file = new File(folder.getAbsoluteFile(), filename) ;
        if (file.exists())
            return stored ;

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            stored = "success";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stored;
    }

    public static File getImage(String imagename) {

        File mediaImage = null;
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File myDir = new File(root);
            if (!myDir.exists())
                return null;

            mediaImage = new File(myDir.getPath() + "/tam/"+imagename);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mediaImage;
    }
    public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename)
    {
        Bitmap b = null ;
        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/"+imagename);
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        if (path != null)
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        if(b == null ||  b.equals(""))
        {
            return false ;
        }
        return true ;
    }

    public static String getImageName(String value){

        String getName[] = value.split("/");
        Log.d("ImagesName",getName[4]);
        return getName[4];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to create bitmap for just checking its exist or not you can check by file only.

```
 public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename) { 
        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + imagename);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }  
    }
```

**Update section:**

And for more speed execution you can add modify your

`public static boolean checkifImageExists(String imagename)`

to

`public static File checkifImageExists(String imagename)`

get file in return if it exists otherwise null then you dont have to do this step again.

```
 public static File checkifImageExists(String imagename) {
        File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + imagename);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return file;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Make some chagne in adapter too.

```
File file = ImageStorage.checkifImageExists(ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl));
        if (file != null) {

            // this step skips
            //File file = ImageStorage.getImage("/" + ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl));
            // and this one also skips
            //String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(file) // why creating new file if you already have same file.
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                    .error(R.drawable.error)
                    .into(holder.menuImage);

        } else {
            new ImageDownloaderTask(list.get(position).imageUrl, holder.menuImage, ImageStorage.getImageName(list.get(position).imageUrl)).execute();
        }
```

**onPostExecute()**

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        // Dont check here you dont have image then you are downloading it.its Already checked?
        // rather then check bitmap you are going to save should not be null
        if (bitmap != null) {
            view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            ImageStorage.saveToSdCard(bitmap, imagename_);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What i do in ImageDownloaderTask.java (onPostExecution)

Comment: @hikoo check updated answer  `onPostExecute` section.

Comment: @hikoo if it help please tick mark and vote up Happy coding :)